# Allowing cancan Ability.rb manage access only specific fields of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm trying to add a button to mark a reply as read in Rails. I currently have something like this.

```
# /app/models/ability.rb
...
can :manage, Reply, :user_id => user.id
...
```

I have also `load_and_authorize_resource` in my RepliesController

```
# /app/controllers/replies_controller.rb
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def update 
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])
    @reply.isRead = true
    if @reply.save
      flash[:notice] = "Marked as ready."
      flash[:alert] = params[:id]
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

I have a button where users can mark a Reply as read.

```
  = button_to "Mark as read", idea_reply_path(reply.idea,reply), :method => "put"
```

Problem is that since I'm trying to update an object from other user.id owner as defined in ability.rb (top) I don't have privileges to edit it.

If I add something like this It will work but I'm also giving rights to manage the whole reply object to the other person.

```
can :manage, Reply, :to_user_id => user.id
```

I'm needing a way to only allow the user to manage the attribute `isRead?` of an object where he's user.id matches the `to_user_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new action for in the controller like mark_as_read

```
 def mark_as_read
  #action to mark as read  
 end
```

and in the abilities define

```
can :manage, :Reply, :user_id => user.id
can :mark_as_read, :to_user_id => user.id
```

The ordering is very important. Now the logged in User can manage Replies and the user who is the user will have only ability to mark_as_read.

Comment: I would suggest to add different action for mark_as_read instead of giving permission for update action. So that Update action can be used for modifying replies

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have both

```
can :manage, Reply, :user_id => user.id
can :update, Reply, :to_user_id => user.id
```

If update action is only for mark Reply as read then that's what you want